# Use php var in js file

Tags: javascript, php

I've been looking, but found nothing similar to my case.

I want my php variable $money , to pass onto my javascript file.

Example :

```
** FILE index.php ** 
<?php $money = 15; ?>

<div id="div-test"> Foo foo<div>

<script src="test.js"></script>


** FILE test.js ** 
document.getElementById("div-test").innerHTML = $money;
```

How would i make this possible?

Comment: Use php tags with echo in  `document.getElementById("div-test").innerHTML = $money;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In php tag

```
<?php $money = 15; ?>


<script>
var val = <?php echo $money; ?>

<div id="div-test"> Foo foo<div>

<script src="test.js"></script>


** FILE test.js ** 
document.getElementById("div-test").innerHTML = val;
</script>
```

Comment: Just the simple answer i was looking for, thank you kindly!

Answer (score 1):

You can't really parse PHP values in a JavaScript file. If you want the value either echo it in place or in a script tag on the PHP page as a variable so you can access it.

```
<div id="div-test"><?php echo $money;?><div>
```

You could then get the text value of #div-test in your JS file.

Or:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var money = <?php echo $money;?>;
</script>
```

Then you could access money as a variable in your test.js file